# Macro to Copy from One Sheet to Another and Sort Ascending

Tags: arrays, excel, sorting, copy-paste, vba

I have an Array formula in the Sheet " Employee Access Detail". (Values are from Column A to D and array formula extends to Row 1530).

I want to copy the values to another sheet called "Employee Access Arranged" and paste as values and then sort ascending according to Column C. I have a code that is working and is as follows :-

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

     ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

     Sheets("Employee Access Arranged").Range("A2:D" & Sheets("Employee 
     Access Arranged").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents

     With Sheets("Employee Access Detail")
    .Range(.Range("A4"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Copy
     End With

    With Sheets("Employee Access Arranged")
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("C2").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    Worksheets("Employee Access Arranged").Activate
    Range("A2").Activate

     End Sub
```

Now, just to paste these values and arrange ascending this code is taking a few minutes and since this has to be done multiple times, is not efficient.

I would be grateful if there was a way this code could be made more efficient. I believe the issues is with how I am copying the values.

Thank you for your help in advance. Appreciate it.

Comment: copy/pastes, activating cells slows down Excel-VBA codes. Instead of copying and pasting try assigning cell values to variables and then assign the new cell values to these variables. You may want to play around with loops and array variables in order to copy multiple cells at once.

Answer (score 0):

Your copy/paste/sort code seems efficient enough, I don't think it is the cause of your lag. I suspect `Activeworkbook.RefreshAll` may be the problem - try commenting it out to see if performance improves.

Copy/Paste/Sort can slow down the process because such operation interacts with the spreadsheet, and reading/writing/updating requires processing power. Try the following:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

` Your code here

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I believe screenupdating and manual calculations have helped reduce the time. The reason I have refresh all is due to the data being updated based on a user access list which is updated quite frequently and I have an external connection linked to the file. Once again, thank you for your help!

Comment: @SalikGilani glad I could help! Do accept the answer so other users know what to do in the future. Cheers!

Comment: I already have. Dont think It will show since I do not have enough reputation points. Hope this helps other people out as well. cheers!